# locking down Apache to localhost

Tags: apache

Having recently moved from Win XP (x86) to Win 7 (x64), I have also had to reinstall Apache. I have installed the 64 bit versions of Apache (2.4.3) and PHP (2.4).

I installed it to c:\Apache24.

I have got it up and running, but now I need to lock it down to my local PC Only.

If I have:

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

Order allow,deny
Allow from all
# New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3 apparently: 
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

this works fine, but if I change it to:

```
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

AllowOverride None

Order allow,deny
Allow from 127.0.0.1
# New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3 apparently: 
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(or 'Allow from Localhost' or 'Allow from 192.x.y.z')

I get an access denied error. How can I get round this?

Everything is installed using my login, which has full local admin rights.

Answer (score 25):

Replace

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
```

by just

```
Require local
```

More: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Comment: `Require all granted` was missing for me. Now its working

Comment: `Require local` - Doesn't allow to access remotely, throws `Forbidden`

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to [add `Listen` to httpd.conf](https://serverfault.com/a/276968/314731):

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Remember to remove the other `Listen` directives, if there are any other.

Note that this will lock down the entire server so it only responds to requests from localhost. If you need to fine-tune permissions on a directory-by-directory basis, use the `<Directory>` syntax:

```
<Directory /var/www/secure>
    Require local
</Directory>
```

The above is for Apache 2.4, where [`Order`, `Allow`, and `Deny` are deprecated](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).